# Encrypt via PHP openssl_public_encrypt, Decrypt via Node.js?

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

I have an existing encryption using...

```
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $publicKey);
return base64_encode($encrypted);
```

And I was wondering if this can be decrypted on node.js? Just a quick question as I could not find similarities with node.js using a public key.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this could help you https://gist.github.com/thepumpkin1979/1300252